# Trouble with many mediaelementjs audio elements on one page

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have 47 mediaelementjs audio elements on one web page.  When I open the page they all try to preload and little blue progress bars fly everywhere.  Some of them make it but others never get started.  The src tag for each of these is pointing to an mp3 file on my dropbox account.  When I click play on ones that never get started they don't play.  What I would like to do is have none of them start downloading unless the user clicks play on one of them.

I tried setting src to '' and setting onclick="this.src='the url'" but this didn't work.  It tried to ask the user to download the missing song.

I will try a coding fix if I need to, but it seems like there should be a simple way to disable preloading until you really need it for cases like this?  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same issue and I figured out that mediaelementjs doesn't support
multiple instances on most browsers. So I used the UbaPlayer for this.
If that isn't feasible, try setting a unique increasing id like player1, player2... on each audio tag
and dynamically instantiate them like this:

```
var players = [];

$('audio').each(function(i){

    players[i] = new MediaElementPlayer('#player'+i, {
        features: ['playpause', 'progress'],
        audioWidth: 250, audioHeight: 30,
        success: function (mediaElement) { mediaElement.pause(); mediaElement.load(); }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there and welcome!

The **simple answer** to your problem is by putting the preload parameter in each audio tag like this:

`<audio src="http://yourdropbox.mp3" preload="none"></audio>`

This should solve the problem of all the players loading at once.

The **longer answer** is that for most applications that many players on one page requires a bit more work to get every video to play properly (believe me I sweated over this myself).

First the preload parameter mentioned earlier I believe does not do anything in IE9.  To fix this I added code that forces IE9 into shim mode.

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({ 
    /*@cc_on
    @if (@_jscript_version == 9)
    mode: 'shim',
    @end
    @*/
    plugins: ['flash','silverlight']
});
```

Now you should be able to have many audio players on one page without any loading problems.  You may find out however, that a handful of players still do not work.  This is because the browser is sending out a request to download every audio file when the mediaelement.js is activated.  It may work on fast internet connections but fail in others.  Hence, the best solution would be to show only a portion of the audio players and then have the user click a button (or scroll to the bottom) to show more of them.